# Creating a certain number of CCSprites automatically

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, instance, multiple-instances, ccsprite

I was looking for a way that I could create multiple instances of a subclass of CCSprite without having to code it manually. The way that my game is going to work is that it shall find the current level number, and then determine the number of sprites that it needs to create depending on that level number. What I was hoping to do is make it so that once that number of sprites has been determined, it then runs a method that creates the instances of those sprites. What would be the best way to do this. This is how I am creating a sprite manually from my subclass at the moment:

```
    Mos *mos = [Mos sprite];
    mos.position = ccp(200,200);
    [self addChild:mos];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set All in One Txt file Or plist. Then Get Value From It And Set Sprite's

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that. Two problems: How? Would it be more effective to assign each type of sprite a value that it then multiplies by the level number and the answer is then the amount of sprites that are initialized?